# tf.keras.layers.concatenate throws a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to run the following got, but I'm getting a syntax error:

```py
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Concatenate, Dense, LSTM, Input, concatenate

nlp_input = Input(shape=(seq_length,), name='nlp_input')
meta_input = Input(shape=(10,), name='meta_input')
embeddings = Embedding(output_dim=embedding_size, input_dim=100, input_length=seq_length)(nlp_input)
nlp_out = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)(embeddings)
x = concatenate([nlp_out, meta_input])
x = Dense(classifier_neurons, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[nlp_input , meta_input], outputs=[x])
```

The error is

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)`  before `(embeddings)`.